# When should I ever use file.read() or file.readlines()?

Tags: python, io, timeit

I noticed that if I iterate over a file that I opened, it is much faster to iterate over it without `read`ing it first. That is:

```
l = open('file','r')
for line in l:
    ...
```

is much faster than

```
l = open('file','r')
for line in l.read(): 
    ...
```

or

```
l = open('file','r')
for line in l.readlines(): 
    ...
```

The 2nd loop will take around 1.5x as much time (I used `timeit` over the exact same file, and the results were 0.442 vs. 0.660), and would give the same result.

So, when should I ever use `.read()` or `.readlines`?

Comment: Please clarify. is the `timeit` measurement for `read`, or for `readlines`? I'd expect the `read` loop to take longer because it returns a single string, so iterating over it would go character-by-character. If your file has on average 100 characters per line, then the code in the `for line in l.read()` loop will execute a hundred times as many times as the code in the `for line in l:` loop.

Comment: it's also for readlines(). Surprisingly there's almost no time difference between read() or readlines()...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that each of these three methods of reading bits of a file have different use cases.  As noted above, `f.read()` reads the file as an individual string, and so allows relatively easy file-wide manipulations, such as a file-wide regex search or substitution.

`f.readline()` reads a single line of the file, allowing the user to parse a single line without necessarily reading the entire file.  Using `f.readline()` also allows easier application of logic in reading the file than a complete line by line iteration, such as when a file changes format partway through.

Using the syntax `for line in f:` allows the user to iterate over the file line by line as noted in the question.

(As noted in the other answer, this documentation is a very good read):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Note:
It was previously claimed that `f.readline()` could be used to skip a line during a for loop iteration.  However, this doesn't work in Python 2.7, and is perhaps a questionable practice, so this claim has been removed.

Comment: Mixing `readline` with a `for` loop over the file doesn't actually work; `readline` doesn't understand the `next` implementation's buffering. If you want to skip a line in a `for` loop, you should call `next` on the file.

Comment: oh, also if you're using regular expressions to search over the string of the file, than it could be a bit faster than iterating over the file.

Answer (score 3):

[From the tutorial included in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> When *size* is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory.... For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:
>
> ```
> >>> for line in f:
> ...     print(line, end='')
> ...
> This is the first line of the file.
> Second line of the file
> ```

Comment: That's not an accurate description of the API for either C or Python.

Comment: I figured I wouldn't explain it very well, that's why I pulled the rest of my answer straight from the documentation.

Comment: C does not default to reading files line by line. There isn't even a standard function for reading files line by line at all in C; `getline` is a POSIX extension. Also, the loop over `f.read()` does not read the entire file on each iteration, and it does not iterate over the lines.

Comment: I wasn't referring to getline, rather fscanf.

Comment: It did last year when I took CS108, not sure when it changed, but I'll be sure to look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115994/discussion-between-rudi-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 3):

```
#The difference between file.read(), file.readline(), file.readlines()
file = open('samplefile', 'r')
single_string = file.read()    #Reads all the elements of the file 
                               #into a single string(\n characters might be included)
line = file.readline()         #Reads the current line where the cursor as a string 
                               #is positioned and moves to the next line
list_strings = file.readlines()#Makes a list of strings
```

Answer (score 2):

> f.read():

**Use Cases:**

1. when reading the whole file as a string.
2. When you want to split the whole file string with a specified delimiter
3. When you want to use the Regular expression on the whole file to search for something.
4. There is only one I/O Operation.

> f.readline()

**Use Cases:**

1. When you want to read one line at a time.
2. one I/O Operation at every line read.

> f.readlines()

**Use Cases:**

1. return the list of lines in the file and include the new line character in each element of the list.
2. One I/O Operation.

Comment: for answering everything in the question, you may add `for line in f` which is basically `iter(f)`. **Use cases:** 1. When you want to lazy iterate a file 2. One or Several I/O Operations (depending on implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `readline()` is not comparable to the case of reading all lines in for-loop since it reads line by line and there is an overhead which is pointed out by others already.

I ran `timeit` on two identical snippts but one with for-loop and the other with `readlines()`. You can see my snippet below:

```
  
def test_read_file_1():  
    f = open('ml/README.md', 'r')  
    for line in f.readlines():  
        print(line)  
  
  
def test_read_file_2():  
    f = open('ml/README.md', 'r')  
    for line in f:  
        print(line)  
  
  
def test_time_read_file():  
    from timeit import timeit  
  
    duration_1 = timeit(lambda: test_read_file_1(), number=1000000)  
    duration_2 = timeit(lambda: test_read_file_2(), number=1000000)  
  
    print('duration using readlines():', duration_1)  
    print('duration using for-loop:', duration_2)
```

And the results:

```
duration using readlines(): 78.826229238
duration using for-loop: 69.487692794
```

The bottomline, I would say, for-loop is faster but in case of possibility of both, I'd rather `readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` is better than `for line in file` when you know that the data you are interested starts from, for example, 2nd line. You can simply write `readlines()[1:]`.

Such use cases are when you have a tab/comma separated value file and the first line is a header (and you don't want to use additional module for tsv or csv files).

Comment: I think you're getting readline() confused with readlines()? Also pretty sure this object isn't indexible post Python-3

Comment: @JonathanSimon you are right, I changed `readline` -> `readlines`

Comment: It would be better to just skip the first line of the file explicitly, by reading it before the loop. The real reason for using `.read` or `.readlines` is because you actually want an in-memory copy for some other reason, as explained in the accepted answer.