# Reading files in Python with for loop

Tags: python

To read a file in Python, the file must be first opened, and then a `read()` function is needed.  Why is that when we use a `for` loop to read lines of a file, no `read()` function is necessary?

```
filename = 'pi_digits.txt'
with open(filename,) as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        print(line)
```

I'm used to the code below, showing the `read` requirement.

```
for line in file_object.read():
```

Comment: In general, you are probably doing something wrong if you call `read` without an argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: When should I ever use file.read() or file.readlines()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105507/python-when-should-i-ever-use-file-read-or-file-readlines)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the file_object class has an "iter" method built in that states how the file will interact with an iterative statement, like a for loop.

In other words, when you say `for line in file_object` the file object is referencing its `__iter__` method, and returning a list where each index contains a line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `open` command in your `with` statement handles the reading implicitly.  It creates a generator that yields the file a record at a time (the `read` is hidden within the generator).  For a text file, each line is one record.

Note that the `read` command in your second example reads the *entire* file into a string; this consumes more memory than the line-at-a-time example.

Comment: Also, `file_object.read()` returns a single string, whose iterator returns a single character at a time, where as a `file` iterator actually returns a line at a time.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the `with` has nothing to do with it. Open the file any other way and the loop will behave the same.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, just unclearly worded. `with open ... as` certainly opens the file (specifically, the call to `open` does; the `with` statement merely ensures it will be closed as well), although it is the resulting `file` object (or whatever `open` ends up returning in Python 3) which produces the iterator used by the `for` loop to actually read from the file.

Comment: I'd say it's misleading, at a minimum. It's hard to read it as _not_ saying, incorrectly, that the `with` plays a role.

Comment: I was keeping the explanation very intro-level, but you guys are right: it's technically misleading, and I need to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Python file objects define special behavior when you iterate over them, in this case with the `for` loop. Every time you hit the top of the loop it implicitly calls `readline()`. That's all there is to it.

Note that the code you are "used to" will actually iterate character by character, not line by line! That's because you will be iterating over a string (the result of the `read()`), and when Python iterates over strings, it goes character by character.