# Printing contents of a file with and without using readlines() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, readlines

I have started learning python and came across the following code to print the contents of a file :

```
with open('Example2.txt','r') as readfile:
     for line in readfile:
          print(line)
```

The output was as follows :

```
This is line A

This is line B

This is line C

This is line D
```

The source if the information says that the `for` loop takes input line by line and then prints it, but as far as I know (please correct me if I am wrong), the variable `readfile` contains a single string then how come the loop is running multiple times? It must be printing the contents of the file in a single go.

Also, this is the code that I think is correct to read the file line by line and this prints the same output too. Then what is the difference between the previous code and this code?

```
with open('Example2.txt','r') as readfile:
     for line in readfile.readlines():
          print(line)
```

Comment: "the variable readfile contains a single string then how come the loop is running multiple times" - Thats not true. readfile is a file object, not a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading files in Python with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168286/reading-files-in-python-with-for-loop)

Comment: readfile is a TextIOWrapp object. It is an iterator. You can iterate. The method readlines returns a list of lines. You can also iterate it as well.

Comment: @afterburner, I got it that it is not a string and is an object then can you please explain what is the difference between the 2 codes I mentioned?

Comment: The readlines method reads the entire file and puts all line in a list. The readfile object, if implemented efficiently will not read the entire file. If you have a big file and don't need everything as the same time, the first method may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `readfile` variable is a file object, which has an `__iter__` method, where each index of the `__iter__` corresponds to a line in your file. For more information, check this similar question: [Reading files in Python with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168286/reading-files-in-python-with-for-loop)

The actual type definition can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapp#io.TextIOWrapper) and it inherits from [BufferedIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapp#io.BufferedIOBase), which in turn inherits from [IOBase](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapp#io.IOBase), where the `readlines` method is defined

The difference between the two code snippets is that in the first one, you're relying on the implementation of `TextIOWrapper`, which is essentially syntactic sugar, to call `readlines` for you, while in the second one, you're explicitly making the call.

Comment: Thank you Pramote, I wasn't sure what the actual class was called.