# Read files from txt

Tags: python, file-io

Given a text file named pop.txt. The content is below:

```
0       1650   
10      1750
20      1860
30      2070
40      2300
50      2560
60      3040
70      3710
80      4450
90      5280
100     6080
110     6870
```

I would like to read it in the get_data function. The output should be like [0,1650],[10,1750]...[110,6870].

```
def get_data(path,name):
    with open(path + file, 'r') as canary:
        x = canary.read().splitlines()
    return x
```

But the output is not what I want. Could you please help me fix my code?

Comment: use `map` and `int` functions to convert from string in integer?

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_data(path,name):
    with open(path + file, 'r') as canary:
        x = canary.readlines()
    parsed_data = []
    for line in x:
        parsed_data.append(line.split())
    return parsed_data
```

If those spaces between the identifiers are actually tabs, you can replace `line.split()` with `line.split('\t')`

As an aside, you should consider using `canary.readlines()` instead of `canary.read().splitlines()` [as outlined here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519749/8763097)

EDIT: I'm not sure if you want your numbers to be strings or integers, but you can cast them to int by using `[int(i) for i in line.split()]`

Comment: instead of `[int(i) for i in line.split()]`, use `map(int, line.split())` also `f'{path}{file}'` is the fastest way to concat strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should use map+split to split each line into two strings and then int to parse as integers.

```
filePath = 'table.txt'
def get_data(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as canary:
        lines = canary.read().splitlines()
        
    return list(map(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.split()], lines))

print(get_data(filePath))
```

Since your file is very small read().splitlines() is okay, but you should use readlines() and loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this:

```
def get_data(path,name):
    with open(path + file, 'r') as canary:
        # you can use this if you want a list with all the entries
        all_lines = []
        for line in canary:
            # this will produce a list of 2 elements (index, number) for each line in your file
            single_line = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
            # appending single line to overall list
            all_lines.append(single_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to effectively turn the function into one statement:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

def get_data(path, name):
    return [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in open(Path(path)/name)]

pprint(get_data('.', 'pop.txt'))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1650],
 [10, 1750],
 [20, 1860],
 [30, 2070],
 [40, 2300],
 [50, 2560],
 [60, 3040],
 [70, 3710],
 [80, 4450],
 [90, 5280],
 [100, 6080],
 [110, 6870]]
```