# Create a dictionary from a list of lines in a text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list of lines in a text file, but my for loop iterates over one line only. What could be the problem. Here is my code

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    dat = f.read()
    datlist=re.compile(r'\n').split(dat)
    dic={}
    for line in datlist:
        dic['location']=re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}',line)[0]
        dic['name']=re.findall(r'-\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s',line)[0][2:].strip()
        dic['time']=re.findall(r'\W[a-zA-Z0-9:/]+\s[-][0-9]+\W',line)[0][1:-1]
        dic['myrequest']=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9-/\.\s]+',line)[0]
        print(dic)
```

I was expecting to create a list of dictionaries from each line, however, I got one only, from the first one.
I tried to change the indent of print(dic) but that could not help, infact, I got a blank dic at some time.

Comment: Where is this list you claim to want, and where are you trying to add anything to it?

Comment: See [When should I use file.read() vs file.readlines()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105507/when-should-i-ever-use-file-read-or-file-readlines)

Comment: If you only create one `dict` in `dic`, and *change* it with each line, why would expect there to be more dictionaries?

Comment: @ScottHunter the list is datlist. It is a list of lines of the text object. I am trying to create a dictionary for each element in the line(a line) and save it in the dictionary dic.  I see your argument. I thought that I will have a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to iterate over lines of text, try using .readlines() instead of .read(), as this will return a list you can interate over, rather than trying to split it over "\n" yourself. Additionally, when you're doing :

```
dic['location']=re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}',line)[0]
dic['name']=re.findall(r'-\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s',line)[0][2:].strip()
dic['time']=re.findall(r'\W[a-zA-Z0-9:/]+\s[-][0-9]+\W',line)[0][1:-1]
dic['myrequest']=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9-/\.\s]+',line)[0]
```

you're adding the result of re.findall to that dict key...but there's only one of each key. I think what you're looking for is one set of location,name,time,myrequest per line, so you'll need to add in a layer for that. You could accomplish this with a nested dictionary, such as (psuedocode):

```
dic = {}
lines = open(file).readlines()
for line in lines:
     page_num = lines.index(line)+1
     dic[page_num] = {}
     dic[page_num]['location']=re.findall(r'[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}',line)[0]
     dic['name']=re.findall(r'-\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s',line)[0][2:].strip()
     dic['time']=re.findall(r'\W[a-zA-Z0-9:/]+\s[-][0-9]+\W',line)[0][1:-1]
     dic['myrequest']=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9-/\.\s]+',line)[0]
```

This way you end up with the heirachy of:

```
--dic
    |--->page 1
           |--->location
           |--->name
           |--->time
           |--->myrequest
    |--->page 2
           |--->location
           |--->name
           |--->time
           |--->myrequest
```

so on and so forth Alternatively, you can bypass adding this extra layer by making the keys of your dictionary a list instead of a string, and appending to the list each time rather than writing over the string